# How do colorblind people see the back of their eyelids?

Tags: vision

When people close their eyes, they still see and they see the back of the eyelids, in colorblind people, they see the back of their eyelids differently, how do colorblind people see the back of their eyelids?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! How do you see the back of your eyelids, and what makes you think that anything would be significantly different for color-blind people?

Comment: The eyelids are translucent, if we face the light, we a reddish color and if we don't face the light, we see a quite not black color, with colorblind people, they see the back of the eyelids differently.

Comment: So if the lit eyelids are "objectively" slightly reddish, then color-blind people perceive them the same way as they perceive other slightly reddish objects–given the type of colorblindness they have. Why would seeing the eyelids be any different than seeing other objects?

Comment: Color blindness varies as much as skin color, some have the genes from both parents, so the results vary. Generally, the difference in color balance can make a red seem more attenuated or brown compared to other colors in a scene, or a blue or green depending on the type of genes they have. It's a comparison of many individual experiences and interpretations of vision, including a psychological interpretative balance.